# Looped Checkbox Array Value Repeated

Tags: arrays, loops, checkbox

I have 4 checkboxes with different values in a while loop & named as an array. The selected value from only the last looped set of checkboxes is being updated yet I need all the selected values (1 per set of 4) to be updated independently to their corresponding rows.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="S" />
<input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="M" />
<input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="L" />
<input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="XL" />
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$select_id = "select * from customer where ip='$ip'";
$get_id = mysqli_query($db, $select_id);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_id)){
foreach($_POST['size'] as $size){

$product_id = $row['product_id'];

$update_size = "update customer set size='$size' where product_id='$product_id'";
$run_size = mysqli_query($db, $update_size);
}
}
}
?>
```

UPDATE - ALMOST THERE!

OUT OF WHILE LOOP

```
$i = 1;
```

IN WHILE LOOP

```
$i++;
<input type="checkbox" name="size[].$i." value="S" />
<input type="checkbox" name="size[].$i." value="M" />
<input type="checkbox" name="size[].$i." value="L" />
<input type="checkbox" name="size[].$i." value="XL" />
```

IN PROCESSING

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$select_id = "select * from customer where ip='$ip'";
$get_id = mysqli_query($db, $select_id);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_id)){

$size = $_POST['size'];
$product_id = $row['product_id'];

foreach ($size as $_POST['size']);
{

$update_size = "update customer set size='$size' where product_id='$product_id'";
$run_size = mysqli_query($db, $update_size);
}
}
}
?>
```

It's now updating different sets of variables per row but now one is a correct value, the other is just array but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was;

```
$size = array_shift($_POST['size']);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the code the foreach loop executes and updates the size field but every time the update statement runs it overwrites the old value. Hence the value of last looped checkbox is stored. You need to check your database structure I think. If you are storing 4 different values for the same product_id the you will need to create a different table (One to many relation). Hope this will help.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, only one checkbox is to be selected, so only 1 of 4 values per row will be stored.

Comment: You can use `<input type="radio" name="size[]" value="S" />` OR add a javascript on checkbox to uncheck other box when any checkbox is clicked. Here is a reference : http://jsfiddle.net/MQM8k/

Comment: I need to increment the name of the checkbox so that the next loop of boxes will be unique.